# PHP, Check if Guzzle headers are being sent?

Tags: php, guzzle

I got problems with this Guzzle, or so I think.
My connection gets rejected, and I think missing headers are the cause.

This is the error I receive:

```
Client error: `GET https://restapi.e-conomic.com/customers` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"message":"Unauthorized access (Unauthorized)."
```

My code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://restapi.e-conomic.com/']);

$headers = [
    'X-AppSecretToken:demo',
    'X-AgreementGrantToken:demo',
    'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'debug' => false
];

$response = $client->request('GET', 'customers', [
    'headers' => $headers
]);
```

Do you guys know how to check, if headers has been sent, and what they contain? Is there a way to verify if the tokens has been submitted?

Regards,

Kenneth

**UPDATE, this works:**

```
$headers = [
    'X-AppSecretToken' => 'demo',
    'X-AgreementGrantToken' => 'demo',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'debug' => false
];

$response = $client->request('GET', 'customers', [
    'headers' => $headers
]);

return $response->getBody();
```

Comment: You used wrong format, `headers` is associative array, so `X-AppSecretToken` => `demo`, not `X-AppSecretToken:demo`

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot mate - stupid mistake by me. Post an answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, `headers` is an associative array, so:

```
[
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
]
```

not:

```
[
    'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8'
]
```

You can read more about Guzzle's PSR-7 implementation (including headers) [here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html).